# Time Calculation over days in Google Sheets to tabulate availability

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

**Overview**

I am trying to tabulate time over days under Google Sheets and see each person's availability based on their start and end times which changes almost every week.

**File Information**
I have this [Sample Availability Timesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IUUuof9GyW6enXJNzAngh-XefFUBoO1kGvcu-IHO14o/edit?usp=sharing) with two Sheet-Tabs.

**Master Sheet-Tab:** This Sheet-Tab contains the list of employees with their respective start-time & end-time.

**Availability Sheet-Tab:** This Sheet-Tab contains the list of employees and a timescale with one hour hop. The resource availability is marked with **Y**, and by **N** if the resource is not available using the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBETWEEN(B$1, VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$C, 2, 0), VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$C, 3, 0))=true, "Y", "N")
```

All works well unless the time hops over the day.

**Problem Area:**
If the start time is 4:00 PM and the end time is 2:00 AM, the scale shows **Y** between 4:00 PM and 11:59 PM but shows **N** between 12:00 AM and 2:00 AM.

I need to show **Y** on both areas, i.e., between 4:00 PM to 11:59 PM and 12:00 AM and 2:00 AM.

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Best Regards,
Syed H

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/113559027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated formula:

`=IF(VALUE(VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$M, 13, 0)) > VALUE(VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$M, 12, 0)), IF(ISBETWEEN(B$1, VALUE(VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$M, 12, 0)), VALUE(VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$M, 13, 0))), "Y", "N"), IF(OR(B$1 <= VALUE(VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$M, 13, 0)), B$1 >= VALUE(VLOOKUP($A2, Master!$A:$M, 12, 0))), "Y", "N"))`

Screenshot from the sheet you've shared with the formula working:

[image]

This version is an extension of the formula you shared. If someone is working from 4PM to 2AM then the way `IFBETWEEN` is being used will throw an error because 2AM is numerically less than 4PM and hence there is nothing in between.

So in cases where someone starts at a PM time and ends at AM time the formula checks for all slots between 12AM and the person working AM and marks them a Y. At the same time the formula also checks for all times in PM that are greater than the person working PM and marks them a Y as well.

If the person starts at a PM time and ends at a greater PM time then it uses your initial version of the formula.

I have made a slight modification to your formula and it should work now.

`=IF($C9>$B9, IF(ISBETWEEN(B$1, VLOOKUP($A2, $A$8:$C, 2, 0), VLOOKUP($A2, $A$8:$C, 3, 0)), "Y", "N"), IF(OR(B$1 <= VLOOKUP($A2, $A$8:$C, 3, 0), B$1 >= VLOOKUP($A2, $A$8:$C, 2, 0)), "Y", "N"))`

[image]

Please remember to remove the dates from some of the cells ex in your sheet the value in `C2` is 12/31/1899 2:00:00 and it should be changed to just 2:00:00.

Comment: Could you tell me what sheets should I look at?

Comment: Thank you for this helpful response. I tried that on the sample data and it worked very well, however, on real one, it did not. I added the replica of real data with dummy names and three Sheet-Tabs. Time Logsheet records local start & end time. Master Sheet-Tab converts time to UTC based on local time and availability sheet shows if a person is available at a given time. I tried your formula with UTC Start and End time in focus, but it didn't work for me. You can see the person **Pista** is working between 4:00 PM - 2:00 AM UTC, however, does not reflect on availability. Please help me.

Comment: I have enabled the **Edit Access** on the sheet. Please help.

Comment: I have updated the formula in the sheet. Updating the answer as well. If this worked for you then please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I am getting an error on the actual data as **"VALUE parameter '2:00: AM' cannot be parsed to number."** The data format and the sheet names are exact matches and the formula should work as a copy, but something is not right, do I make any further change?

Comment: When I look in your sheet the formula is working as intended. I have pasted the screenshot in the answer as well. Where are you getting this error? Have you tried checking if the way time values have been entered is correct?

Comment: Here is the copy of the sheet [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AR2VGLhW8sh6ga4pEt_R3XZi39gBRdlHpgUa_nsw3BY/edit#gid=1862571210 with error. The formula is only under Column B of availability sheet.

Comment: Dear Broly, please review the [document] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AR2VGLhW8sh6ga4pEt_R3XZi39gBRdlHpgUa_nsw3BY/edit#gid=1862571210) I have added in the last comment before this one and see if you can help me fix it. Your trick seem to work, however, for unknown reason I am getting that parse error. Please help.

Comment: It worked; I just had to change the format to get rid of the tailing **:** in the time format after minutes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Would you be kind to explain the formula to me in detail. It will be a great help in my learning;

Comment: Add the explanation in the answer. Glad it worked for you.